# Why a proximinal subspace closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $M$ be a subspace of a normed space $X$. We say that $M$ is proximinal if $$\forall x\in X \; \exists y\in M \; :\; \| x-y\|=dist(x,M),$$ where $dist(x,M)=\inf_{m\in M}\| x-m\|$.
Why  $M$ is closed?

What 've tired: Let $\{ y_n \}\subset M$ such that $y_n \to y$. Then by definition, there exists  $\{ x_n \}\subset X$ such that $\| x_n -y_n \|=dist(x_n ,M)$. My problem is now that I can't find some $x\in X$ such that $\| x -y \|=dist(x ,M)$.

Is there anyone who helps me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y_n \to y_0$ with $(y_n) \subset M$. Apply the hypothesis with $x=y_0$. There exists $z \in M$ such that $\|z-y_0\|=\inf \{d(y_0,z):z \in M\}$. But then   $\|z-y_0\|=\inf \{d(y_0,z):z \in M\}\leq \|y_o-y_n\|$ for all $n$. Letting $n \to \infty$ we get $\|z-y_0\|=0$ which means $z=y_0$. Hence, $y_0=z \in M$ proving tha $M$ is closed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice answer.